# use sed to remove content between two characters, but up to that point and not till the end if that character comes up again

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Example I: I want to keep 'W' 
file: `input.txt`
contents:

```
ab
ab ab z
ab z ab W ab z ab
```

Command:

```
sed 's/ab.*ab/~/g' input.txt
```

Result:

```
ab
~ z
~
```

Goal:

```
ab
~ z
~ W ~
```

Example II:
Goal: keep blob 
File: `input.txt`
Contents:

```
<\ab>
<\!DOCTYPE html> blob <>
<\!DOCTYPE html> blob <> blob2  <
```

Command:

```
sed 's/<.*>/~/g' input.txt
```

Result:

```
~
~
~ blob2  <
```

Goal:

```
~
~ blob ~
~ blob ~ blob2 <
```

Unfortunately only blob2 survived. Help me save blob one?

It looks like `sed` will find the first instance of '<' and the last instance of '>' and remove what is in between. I'm trying to get sed to replace between the *next* instance of '>' not the last.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format your code and sample input/output blocks legibly and then [edit] your question to suit.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

Taking example II first:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>/~/g' file
```

By matching on zero or more not a `>` until a `>` we prevent a greedy `.*` from swallowing the entire line and then pattern matching working back along the line.

Example I:

```
sed '/ab.*ab/!b;s/ab/\n/g;s/\n[^\n]*\n/~/g;s/\n/ab/' file
```

If a line does not contain two or more `ab` leave it alone. Otherwise, replace all `ab`'s by a unique character such as `\n` and the using the same trick as in Example II, replace `\n[^\n]*\n` by `~`. However there maybe an odd number of `ab`'s, so replace such an occurrence by its original value.